# Polymorphism and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have these classes:

```
class A
 {
    public int Foo()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int Foo() 
    {
        return 1; 
    }
}
```

and I use them like this:

```
        B b = new B();
        int x = b.Foo();
```

and although Foo() in the base class isn't virtual, or in the derived class - it hasn't the override keyword, still x equals 1. Then, what is the use of the virtual and override keywords?

Comment: Which language are you using? C#? Java?

Comment: @Luchi it seems to be C#, not Java. It has `:` instead of `extends` and talks about `virtual`/`override` keywords. Naming conventions also follow .net, not Java. So I think tagging it with C# is appropriate.

Comment: C#. I didn't put a tag because Java knows of inheritance also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymorphism allows type B to be treated as type A.

```
A b = new B();
int x = b.Foo(); // x will be 1 if virtual, 5 if not.
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is C#:

You didn't override `Foo`. You hid the `Foo` of the baseclass. This means that if you call foo an a variable with the static type `B` you will get `B.Foo()` and calling on the static type `A` (even if the type is `B` at runtime) will give you `A.Foo()`.

Your code should give a compiler warning, since you're hiding the base method without using the `new` keyword.

```
B b = new B();
int x = b.Foo();//calls B.Foo
A a = b;//Runtime type B, compiletime type A
a.Foo(); // calls A.Foo
```

If you had overridden `Foo` then you'd get `B.Foo()` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Marking a method as `virtual` allows it to be *polymorphic*. That means that it can be overridden in derived classes. A polymorphic method comes into play when you call it from a base class *reference*. The method that's going to get called at runtime depends on the runtime class of the object pointed by the base class reference. If its runtime type is the base class itself, the method called will be the one on the base class; if the runtime type is of a derived type that has overridden that method, the method called will be that overridden method.

If the method is not `virtual`, it will be bound to call the method that's declared in the type of the compile time reference to the object, regardless of its runtime type.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaring type is B thus you will call the implementation of B.. if your declaring type is A and you are instantiating new instance of B then you get 5 as the declaring type unless you use virtual keyword to support polymorphysm ..

Answer (score 0):

The point of making the method virtual is when you call the method via a base class pointer or reference:

`A p = new B();

int x = p.Foo();`

In this example, the static type of p is `A`, but the dynamic type is `B`. This means that, due to polymorphism, `B.Foo` is called although the static type is `A`.

Comment: Do you mean something like ((A)b).Foo();

Comment: The question is about Java. p->Foo() doesn't exits in Java.

Comment: Oops, sorry - I was thinking C++!

Comment: Also A* p = new B; isn't legal in Java... A p = new B();, with parenthesis, is different.

Comment: +1: even though your example was in C++, it showed the right _concepts_. I've updated it to match the question's language.